# Overloaded method not being used?

Tags: java, parameters, overloading, jmf

I'm attempting to use the JMF to create background music for my project.

From what I understand, the method Manager.createPlayer(); can use InputStreams, URLs, and DataSources.

However, when I use the following code:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/03-redial.mp3");
Player aPlayer = Manager.createPlayer(is,"audio/mpeg");
aPlayer.start();
```

I end up getting this:

"The method createPlayer(URL) in the type Manager is not applicable for the arguments (InputStream, String)"

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [javadoc for JMF Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/apidocs/javax/media/Manager.html) shows 3 versions of createPlayer; each of them take only one argument (either DataSource, MediaLocator, or URL).  None of them take two parameters.  If you've seen a two-parameter version of the method, perhaps you are using a different version than the one you saw?

Comment: I apparently was looking at a the microedition's Manager class. Whoops!